# RegExp word boundary with special characters (.) javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find "U.S.A." (without the quotes) if it is in a string as a whole word.

So good strings should be

```
U.S.A.
u.s.a.
U.S.A. is a great country
Is this U.S.A. ?
```

Bad string is

```
U.S.A.mnop
U.S.A
```

I tried using

```
/\bU\.S\.A\.\b/i
```

But strangely the one that works is - (But it fails for other countries and so not useful)

```
/\bU\.S\.A\.\B/i
```

This seems opposite of my understanding from documentation and have searched this and there are lots of similar problems but none of them helped me understand the issue. I think that the last "." is being consumed by \b and hence not working but am still confused.

Can someone please help with explanation and the right search string ? It should also do proper word search of other strings without special characters.

Comment: revised - What about this? https://regex101.com/r/YKa7OM/2

Comment: @0m3r - Thanks but it matches U.S.A.daddy and daddyU.S.A. as well which is not desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the word boundary first (as you were doing), but the tricky part is at the end where you can't use the word boundary because of the `.`. However, you can check for a whitespace character at the end instead:

```
/\b(u\.s\.a\.)(?:\s|$)/gi
```

Check out the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9TVuPn/4)

Comment: Works.... Works... Thanks for that. Although I am not super happy as I have to put in all kinds of special characters to figure out the word end => for now using the below - 
   / \b(u\.s\.a\.)(?:(\s|$|\.|\?))/gi

Will loose this battle and move on with the war for the time being but will revisit

Comment: @shirishc, could you just add "not a letter or number" to the end?
`\b(u\.s\.a\.)(?:\s|$|[^\w])` [Check out this example](https://regex101.com/r/9TVuPn/5)

Comment: Certainly much cleaner. Thanks. Somehow I always seem to miss the NOT usage in everything in life !!!